# Class not showing anything when complied..what could be reason?

Tags: python, atom-editor

When I am running this code in ATOM .. it does not showing the result but just plain this ... Any idea why it is not working in ATOM editior? I tried to change the indentation but still no result just plain text in the terminal of ATOM

```
[Finished in 0.229s] 


class myClass():
    def method1(self):
        print("A class this is number 2 ")

    def method2(self, something):
        print("A class this is number 1 " + something)

def main():
    c = myClass()
    c.method1()
    c.method2("some words here")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: Your `if __name == "__main__"` is inside the `main()` function. Move it out and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad indentation, try this:

```
class myClass():
    def method1(self):
        print("A class this is number 2 ")

    def method2(self, something):
        print("A class this is number 1 " + something)

def main():
    c = myClass()
    c.method1()
    c.method2("some words here")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
A class this is number 2 
A class this is number 1 some words here
```

Comment: @AntonioMendoza no worries, you may mark the answer by clicking on the tick sign beside it. cheers

Comment: Done, thanks for help ... I am diving into Python world